# Ionic app crashes on android device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have followed Ionic basic tutorials and tried to run the app on emulator, it worked but while deploying on android real device (5.1.1), it launches and then crashed. Following is logcat:

```
12-04 21:04:01.895: I/Timeline(6231): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.ionicframework.myapp111834 time:6198882
12-04 21:04:01.898: I/ActivityManager(1383): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.ionicframework.myapp111834/.MainActivity (has extras)} from uid 10034 on display 0
12-04 21:04:01.915: V/WindowManager(1383): addAppToken: AppWindowToken{181c670c token=Token{31f0523f ActivityRecord{d4eee5e u0 com.ionicframework.myapp111834/.MainActivity t48}}} to stack=1 task=48 at 0
12-04 21:04:01.921: V/WindowManager(1383): Adding window Window{1b17926a u0 Starting com.ionicframework.myapp111834} at 5 of 9 (after Window{191b3266 u0 com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings})
12-04 21:04:01.980: I/ActivityManager(1383): Start proc 12515:com.ionicframework.myapp111834/u0a96 for activity com.ionicframework.myapp111834/.MainActivity
12-04 21:04:02.506: V/WindowManager(1383): Adding window Window{24ba494b u0 com.ionicframework.myapp111834/com.ionicframework.myapp111834.MainActivity} at 5 of 10 (before Window{1b17926a u0 Starting com.ionicframework.myapp111834})
12-04 21:04:02.535: V/WindowManager(1383): Adding window Window{2bd14441 u0 com.ionicframework.myapp111834/com.ionicframework.myapp111834.MainActivity} at 5 of 11 (before Window{24ba494b u0 com.ionicframework.myapp111834/com.ionicframework.myapp111834.MainActivity})
12-04 21:04:02.724: I/ActivityManager(1383): Displayed com.ionicframework.myapp111834/.MainActivity: +796ms
12-04 21:04:02.724: I/Timeline(1383): Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{d4eee5e u0 com.ionicframework.myapp111834/.MainActivity t48} time:6199711
12-04 21:04:04.521: I/DEBUG(805): pid: 12515, tid: 12560, name: Thread-1329  >>> com.ionicframework.myapp111834 <<<
12-04 21:04:06.158: W/ActivityManager(1383):   Force finishing activity 1 com.ionicframework.myapp111834/.MainActivity
12-04 21:04:06.317: I/WindowState(1383): WIN DEATH: Window{24ba494b u0 com.ionicframework.myapp111834/com.ionicframework.myapp111834.MainActivity}
12-04 21:04:06.322: I/WindowState(1383): WIN DEATH: Window{2bd14441 u0 com.ionicframework.myapp111834/com.ionicframework.myapp111834.MainActivity}
12-04 21:04:06.333: I/ActivityManager(1383): Process com.ionicframework.myapp111834 (pid 12515) has died
12-04 21:05:08.669: W/PackageManager(5663): Failure retrieving resources for com.ionicframework.myapp111834: Resource ID #0x0
```

P.S.: I have used tabs example, blank as well as conference tutorials.

Thanks.